# Hidden screens and hidden states in your app, how do you surface them all when redesigning?

Tags: workflow, mockup, redesign, application-state

We're making a change to our pricing model that will mean we need to update a number of system messages and upgrade prompts throughout the interface. These messages are largely based on user context, as in they can be different for different types of users at different stages of their journey. The message content can depend on variables such as:

- user role / permissions
- account type
- level of progression in a flow
- previous actions
- market segment
- version of product

Some of these states I'm aware of from previous mockups and flow diagrams. But often it involves going to a developer and asking them to write a script to generate all of the possible states so I know what needs to be updated and don't miss anything.

I'm wondering what other designers do. Is there a product out there that makes this easier? Are you organised enough to just consult your UX documentation and that covers all the scenarios? Or do you rely on developers to help reveal the different states?

Answer (score 1):

We normally plan and spec out and list all the states across the entire product for the developer. If there are missing states, the developer will bring them up and ask us how to handle them.

For projects where documentation is not available, we would simply click through and inventory all the states we find. And, working backwards, slowly mapping out the taskflows previously designed. A website crawler can generate a list of all the urls, but each url still needs to be inventoried and made sense within the sitemap or taskflow.